# Show that $\sum _{k=1}^\infty (1-\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k})$ converges iff $(x_k)_k$ is bounded.

Tags: sequences-and-series

For monotonic increasing $(x_k)_k$ and $x_k >0$.

My thoughts:
Obviously, I'll have to prove both directions.

For the first direction:

If $(x_k)_k$ bounded, then $x_k \overset{n}{\rightarrow} a$ where $a>0$, so the term inside the sum essentially goes to 0, $(1-\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k}) \overset{n}{\rightarrow} 0$. But this isn't enough to prove convergence of the sum. So I'm kind of stuck there.

For the other dircetion:

If the sum converges, my above argument applies (the term inside of the sum converges to 0). So $\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k} \overset{n}{\rightarrow} 1$. <del>I guess it's obvious at this point, that $(x_k)_k$ converges at this point</del> . Please correct me if needed (Thanks, Hagen).
<del>From this it follows immediately, that $(x_k)_k$ is bounded.</del>

Comment: If $x_k\to a\ne0$ then $1+\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k}\to 2$, I'm afraid. Also, $\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k}\to 1$ does not implie $x_k$ is bounded: consider $x_k=k$.

Comment: Not to mention that $x_n$ may be bounded and without limit.

Comment: sorry, I fixed the + - error

Answer (score 2):

Note that 
$$ \ln(x_N) - \ln(x_1) = \sum_{j=1}^{N-1} \ln\left(\dfrac{x_{j+1}}{x_j}\right)$$
Now use the fact that
$$ \lim_{t \to 1} \dfrac{\ln(t)}{t-1} = 1$$